# Analytic implies harmonic

Tags: complex-analysis

Claim: The real and imaginary parts of an analytic function are harmonic

Proof:
Let $f=u+iv $ be analytic in some open set of the complex plane.
$$  
\frac {\partial^2 u}{\partial x^2}+\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial y^2}
$$
$$
=\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\frac{\partial u}{\partial x} + \frac{\partial}{\partial y}\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}
$$
$$
=\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\frac{\partial v}{\partial y} - \frac{\partial}{\partial y}\frac{\partial v}{\partial x}(using \ Cauchy-Riemann)
$$
$$
=\frac{\partial^2 v}{\partial x\partial y}-\frac{\partial^2 v}{\partial x\partial y}=0
$$

What I am confused about:
In line 4, how do we know the mixed partials are equal. Doesn't v have to be $ C_2 $ for the mixed partials to be equal. Does analytic imply $C_2?$

Comment: You can talk about harmonicity only once you know that $u$ and $v$ are $C^2$. Once they are $C^2$, it follows that the mixed partials are equal. But do you know a proof of why they are $C^2$ in the first place? (By that, I  mean that analyticity does imply $C^2$ property of the component functions, but do you know the reason for that?) If you do not, then look up power series expansions of holomorphic functions.

Comment: Every analytic function is $C^\infty$.

Comment: May I know why it is $C^\infty$

Comment: @matt see Ponnusamy S., Silverman H., Complex Variables with Applications, Birkhauser (2006), page 243.